# file not found,jenkins pipline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, terragrunt

I am getting file not found error on my Jenkins job.

```
    if (component_meta ==null)
    echo "path = " + component_meta
    else if (component_meta.tf_version !=null){
    echo "path = " + component_meta
    echo "version = " + component_meta.tf_version
    dir ("base/" + component_meta.path){
    sh 'rm -rf .terra*'
    sh "terragrunt plan --terragrunt-tfpath /usr/local/bin/tf/versions/" + component_meta.tf_version + "/terraform" + " -detailed-exitcode"
    }
}
```

error I beleive is in the system of below command

```
sh "terragrunt plan --terragrunt-tfpath /usr/local/bin/tf/versions/" + component_meta.tf_version + "/terraform" + " -detailed-exitcode"
```

Comment: Can you share the  pipeline logs as well?

Comment: What is the `agent` directive?